# ODE - Why Bernoulli

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I forgot what the original exercise looked like (you can get it be by substituting u back again, but it is not relevant) but in class, by using the $u$ substitution $u = y+1$ and $dy=du$, the professor got to a point where we had:

$$\frac{du}{dx} = u + x u^2$$

He then moved the $u$ to the left side, making it a Bernoulli's equation:

$$\frac{du}{dx} - u = x u^2$$

Now my question is: instead of solving this the way you solve Bernoulli's equations, couldn't I simply integrate both sides of $\displaystyle \frac{du}{dx} = u + x u^2$?
That would yield $\displaystyle u = ux + \frac{x^2u^2}{2}$, and by substituting $u$ back, I would get the desired function in terms of $x$ and $y$. That clearly was not the same answer he got using Bernoulli's method, why?

thanks!

Comment: Because $u$ is not a constant, but a function of $x$- so your method is wrong.

Comment: @voldemort Wait - $u=y+1$. So, since $y=y(x)$, $u=u(x)$. Therefore, $u$ is not a constant.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar: That's what I wrote.

Comment: @voldemort I'm so sorry. I accidentally read your comment as "$u$ is a constant"

Comment: @voldemort I see, isn't u a function of y though ?

Comment: @Lucas: and $y$ is a function of $x$. So $u$ really is a function of $x$